# Why is my Linux application constantly changing state from R to S+ on Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, process, state

My application writes files to disk after every X hours. The application runs a typical simulation and sometimes takes 2 to 3 days to complete. The same code runs on Windows successfully however the Linux version changes state from R to S+ sometimes on some servers (Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS). On some servers the simulation runs successfully. Is this a power setting or file IO hunging? Thanks.

Comment: What "state" are you referring to? Something seen in `ps`/`top`/etc.? Or something internal to the application? Or ...? This can't be answered without more information, I think...

Comment: I am running the application in screen and from the console it doesn't seem to have crashed. On another screen terminal i.e. using screen command Ctrl+A+C I typed "top" and it doesn't list my application. I then typed "ps aux" and it shows the application as "S1+". The interesting thing is that the application is listed with details of its currrent memory consumption which is about 9GB RAM which is correct but it seems to be sleeping. I also checked the "%wa" and there's nothing writing to disk or busy.

Comment: I am running the same application in 3 different servers as a test and this is what i have noticed : Server1 is running fine in a screen session with no problems. Server2 is also running fine in screen with no problems. However, Server three has changed state to "S1+" and its not listed when I use command "top" but the difference between all servers is that Server3 has mounted a network drive and just to make it clear Server3 is not reading or writing data to the mounted drive in any way. Could this be the bottleneck?

Comment: Is the cifs mounted drive causing problems? The mounted drive is auto mounted by adding cifs command in the system "etc/fstab" file.

Comment: I have tried sending signals "sudo kill -SIGCONT PID" to the terminal but it doesn't do anything. I have also tried the "fg" and "bg" commands and nothing works.

Comment: [Just Edited] I noticed Server1 has also mounted the network drive but not via editing the "etc/fstab" file - It mounted the drive using command line "mount.cifs //0.0.0.0/DriveName ~/MountedDrive -o user=username"

Comment: According to `man ps`, your "state" "Sl+" means three things - "+" indicates a foreground process group (it's not being run in the background, and it has an associated terminal), "l" (note it's not the number "1") means it's multi-threaded, and "S" means it's in an interruptible sleep state - typically waiting for I/O (not necessarily disk, though - could be terminal input or network or ...) or a timer wakeup or something. It just means that, at the exact point "ps" read through it's process information, it was not currently running. Is this a multi-CPU system?

Comment: I have a bit more info to add as I have just finished analyzing the results of my previous tests involving running the application on 3 different computers with same spec(3.5GHz multi-core processor and 16GB RAM and 1TB HDD). One of the servers run the app just fine with no problems. 2 servers failed as the application showing to be in "S1+" state when I type "ps aux" and not being listed when i type "top". I run the application inside a screen session if that helps too. Thanks.